# "Robot Arm moving block stacks" Programming Challenge in C

Tags: c, algorithm, recursion, tree

I'm trying to resolve this for fun but I'm having a little bit of trouble on the implementation, the problem goes like this:

*Having n stacks of blocks containing m blocks each, design a program in c that controlls a robotic arm that moves the blocks form an inicial configuration to a final one using the minimum amount of movements posible, your arm can only move one block at a time and can only take the block at the top of the stack, your solution should use either pointers or recursive methods*

In other words the blocks should go from this(suposing there are 3 stacks and 3 blocks):

```
| || || |
|3|| || |
|2||1|| |
```

to this:

```
| ||1|| |
| ||2|| |
| ||3|| |
```

using the shortest amount of movements printing each move

I was thinking that maybe I could use a tree of some sorts to solve it (n-ary tree maybe?) since that is the perfect use of pointers and recursive methods but so far it has proved unsuccesfull, I'm having lots of trouble defining the estructure that will store all the movements since I would have to check every time I want to add a new move to the tree if that move has not been done before, I want each leaf to be unique so when I find the solution it will give me the shortest path.

This is the data structure I was thinking of:

```
typedef struct tree(
char[MAX_BLOCK][MAX_COL] value;    
struct tree *kids
struct tree *brothers;
)Tree;
```

(I'm really new at C so sorry beforehand if this is all wrong, I'm more used to Java)

How would you guys do it? Do you have any good ideas?

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, this sounds like [Tower of Hanoi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi)

Comment: @BurhanKhalid, not really, since the block stacking isn't restricted in any way.

Comment: Good point - the desired result `1 > 2 > 3` - is what looks like ToH. For the OP, looking at ToH solutions in C would be beneficial though.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid indeed the stacking is not limited in any way, it can start and end with any configuration given, precisely I thought of recursion because taht's the way you solve ToH

Comment: Is there a constraint that no stack may ever be taller than m at any intermediate time?

Comment: Not at all, although with a low number of stacks and a high number of blocks the problem would be unsolvable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the basic idea - though I am not sure why you have elected to choose brothers over the parent.

You *can* do this problem with a simple BFS search, but it is a slightly less interesting solution, and not the one you for which seemed to have set yourself up.

I think it will help if we concisely and clearly state our approach to the problem as a formulation of either [Dijkstra's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm), A*, or some other search algorithm.

If you are unfamiliar with Dijkstra's, it is imperative that you read up on the algorithm before attempting any further. It is one of the foundational works in shortest path exploration.

With a familiarity of Dijkstra's, A* can readily be described as

> Dijsktra's minimizes distance from the start. A* adds a heuristic which minimizes the (expected) distance to the end.

With this algorithm in mind, lets state the specific inputs to an A* search algorithm.

> Given a start configuration *S-start*, and an ending configuration *S-end*, can we find the shortest path from S-start to S-end given a set of rules *R* governed by a reward function *T*

Now, we can envision our data structure not as a tree, but as a graph. Nodes will be board states, and we can transition from state to state using our rules, R. We will pick which edge to follow using the reward function T, the heuristic to A*.

What is missing from your data-structure is the cost. At each node, you will want to store the current shortest path, and whether it is finalized.

Let's make a modification to your data-structure which will allow us to readily traverse a graph and store the shortest path information.

```
typedef struct node {
  char** boardState;
  struct node *children;
  struct node *parent;
  int distance;
  char status; //pseudo boolean
} node;
```

> You may want to stop here if you were interested in discovering the algorithm for yourself.

We now consider the rules of our system: one block at a time, from the top of a stack. Each move will constitue an *edge* in our graph, whose weight is governed by the shortest number of moves from S-begin plus our added heuristic.

We can then sketch a draft of the algorithm as follows:

```
node * curr = S-begin;
while (curr != S-end) {
  curr->status == 'T'; //T for True
  for(Node child : children) {
     // Only do this update if it is cheaper than the 
     int updated = setMin(child->distance, curr->distance + 1 + heuristic(child->board));
     if(updated == 1) child->parent = curr;  
  } 
  //set curr to the node with global minimum distance who has not been explored
}
```

You can then find the shortest path by tracing the parents backwards from S-end to S-begin.

If you are interested in these types of problems, you should consider taking a uppergraduate level AI course, where they approach these types of problems :-)

Comment: Oh - just to mention, if you decide to use a heuristic based approach, make sure your heuristic is [monotonic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function)

Comment: Excelent! I actually solved this using BFS but this is wonderful! I will definitely rewrite my code with his in mind, Thanks! :D